# How do I inject a single property value into a string using spring 2.5.x?

Tags: java, spring

I would really like to annotate a method with a reference to a single property in a property file for injection.

```
@Resource("${my.service.url}")
private String myServiceUrl;
```

Of course, this syntax does not work ;) Thats why I'm asking here.

I am aware that I can inject the full properties file, but that just seems excessive, I dont want the property file - I want the configured value.

Edit: I can only see PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer examples where XML is used to wire the property to the given field. I still cannot figure out how this can be achieved with an annotation ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a thread about this on the [Spring forum](http://forum.springframework.org/showthread.php?t=50790). The short answer is that there's really no way to inject a single property using annotations.

I've heard that the support for using annotations will be improved in Spring 3.0, so it's likely this will be addressed soon.

Answer (score 7):

I know it has been a while since the original post but I have managed to stumble across a solution to this for spring 2.5.x

You can create instances of "String" beans in the spring xml configuration which can then be injected into the Annotated components

```
@Component
public class SomeCompent{
  @Autowired(required=true 
  @Resource("someStringBeanId")
  private String aProperty;

  ...
}

<beans ....>
   <context:component-scan base-package="..."/>

  <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    ...
  </bean>
  <bean id="someStringId" class="java.lang.String" factory-method="valueOf">
    <constructor-arg value="${place-holder}"/>
  </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: This solution is not working for me. First of all there seem to be syntax errors all over the place- you're missing the right paren after the autowire declaration, and the resource annotation is missing the name attribute. Finally, I get a BeanCreationException with this XML :(

Answer (score 5):

I've created a project which addresses this problem for Spring 2.5.*:

http://code.google.com/p/spring-property-annotations/

For Spring 3 you can use the @Value("${propery.key}") annotation.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this if you use XML configuration. Just configure PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer and specify property value in configuration

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <value>classpath:com/foo/jdbc.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean ...>
  <property name="myServiceUrl" value="${my.service.url}"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score -2):

You could try injecting value of property "my.service.url" to a filed in your bean.

Take a look at: http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer

HTH.