# Spring: Setting a property annotated with @Resource

Tags: spring, spring-annotations

This following does not behave like I expect, using Spring 3.2.1.RELEASE, groovy 1.8.8. I've elided quite a bit of code. If this isn't sufficient, I'll put together a (not) working full example.

groovy bean:

```
package foo

import javax.annotation.Resource

class SomeBean {
    @Resource
    String someProp
}
```

spring xml:

```
<context:annotation-config />

<context:component-scan base-package="other.packages.not.foo" />

<bean id="someBean" class="foo.SomeBean">
    <property name="someProp" value="bar" />
</bean>
```

This fails with an error about not being able to find a bean to satisfy the String property. To work around this, I ended up doing this:

groovy bean:

```
@Resource( name = 'someProp' )
String someProp
```

spring xml:

```
<bean id="someProp" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="bar" />
</bean>

<bean id="someBean" class="foo.SomeBean" />
```

I don't like this solution, because it couples the bean source code to the spring config, and that's coupling in the wrong direction. And it creates an unnecessary bean for a simple String. Am I missing an obvious solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I inject a single property value into a string using spring 2.5.x?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217718/how-do-i-inject-a-single-property-value-into-a-string-using-spring-2-5-x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Resource is not meant for property injection.

For this to work:

```
<bean id="someBean" class="foo.SomeBean">
  <property name="someProp" value="bar" />
</bean>
```

you need to implement a setter method

```
public void setSomeBean(String value) {
  someValue = value;
}
```

@Resource could be used if you want to inject a different bean from your context.

```
@Resource(name="someBean")
SomeBean someBean
```

Comment: It's groovy, not java. So the setter is created by the compiler. I should have pointed out that if I remove the Resource annotation, it also works. My understanding is that it is meant to annotate those properties which must be set prior to deployment. Is that not the case? This String is a required property.

Comment: I think you are confusing @ Resource with @ Required. @ Resource injects a bean from the context. @ Required makes a property as mandatory, so the context initialization fails if the property is not specified in the context description.

Comment: I better understand the semantic differences now. I was trying to avoid spring annotations in my java, so it seems like the right answer here is to use @ Inject. My understanding is now that @ Resource should be reserved for sharable components with their own life cycle, perhaps used by others than just your service.